# How do I access the value of the link button outside the form and pass it into the form via post method?

Tags: php, file, system

This are the two options. I want to select one of the button link and have to get the value via post method when I submit the form
Please, how do I go about it? To catch the value of the link having a data-value for rent if it is clicked and vice versa for the data-value having for-sale, and then when I click on the submit button, I want to catch that value and relate it to the search button.

```
 <div class="mxw-670 position-relative z-index-2">
                <input class="search-field" type="hidden" name="status" value="for-sale" data-default-value="">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills property-search-status-tab">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link btn shadow-none rounded-bottom-0 fs-13 letter-spacing-087 bg-dark-opacity-05 text-white hover-white text-uppercase bg-active-primary active"
                            data-toggle="pill" data-value="for-sale" href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="true" form="message">
                            sale
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link btn shadow-none rounded-bottom-0 fs-13 letter-spacing-087 bg-dark-opacity-05 text-white hover-white bg-active-primary text-uppercase"
                            data-toggle="pill" data-value="for-rent" href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="false" form="message">
                            rent
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form action="" method="post" id="message" class="d-flex">
                    <div class="position-relative w-100">
                        <i class="far fa-search text-dark fs-18 position-absolute pl-4 pos-fixed-left-center"></i>
                        <input type="text"
                            class="rounded-bottom-right-lg w-100 pl-8 py-4 bg-white border-0 fs-13 font-weight-500 text-gray-light rounded-0 lh-17"
                            placeholder="Enter an address, neighborhood" name="search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn-primary fs-16 font-weight-600 rounded-left-0 rounded-lg">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you use `jQuery` in your project?

Comment: I'd say you want to include those "buttons" into the form and turn them into radio buttons of a common group.

Comment: I guess he wants to send the link `data-value` in the form submission data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your button an `input type button` and submit the form with `jQuery Ajax` call

```
<input type="button" id="submitButton" name="submit"  class="btn btn-primary fs-16 font-weight-600 rounded-left-0 rounded-lg" value="Search" />
```

And in your javascript code,

```
$('input#submitButton').click( function() {
    $.post( 'some-url', $('form#myForm').serialize(), function(data) {
         // ... do something with the response from the server
       },
       'JSON' // I expect a JSON response
    );
});

$('input#submitButton').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some-url',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
                   // ... do something with the data...
                 }
    });
});
```

In the `data` field in the `ajax` call, you can add the value of the link having a `data-value` attribute using `$(element).attr('data-value')`